# PHP alert message

Tags: php, javascript, database, alert

I know the first thing everyone is going to say is that this has been posted hundreds of times; however, I have tried all the different methods people have suggested with still no luck... I am trying to get an alert message to popup if the login fails but for some reason the message does not want to appear. Here's what I have so far:

```
if($conn) {
    $result=sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Operator
    WHERE Username='{$_POST['login']}'");
    $pass=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
    if($pass["Password"] === $_POST['password']) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin']=true;
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header("Location: login.php");
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Password Invalid!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

The php is working fine but for some reason I can't get the javascript to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also show us the javascript that is not working? Also, open your network tab in browser dev console. Does your ajax ever goes through?

Comment: Right click and inspect your document, is the <script> tag being echoed before the <html> tag?

Comment: If you're setting a redirector with `Location` the script will never appear.

Comment: @zladuric from his line  header("Location: login.php"); it's obvious it's not ajax and he's redirecting

Comment: @zladuric There is only one part where I'm using java... I'm trying to include the javascript inside the php code.

Comment: It looks to me like you're storing your passwords in plain text. That's a huge security issue. Check out this SO question for implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: Try adding a query string to the end of your "login.php" redirect so that it looks like "login.php?status=error". Then you can add a conditional that checks $_GET["status"] and output the alert there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think, the problem is here. you are redirecting the page before the alert message

```
header("Location: login.php"); /* Redirect browser */
```

try removing it, or make it redirect after a couple of seconds, like this

```
header( "refresh:5;url=login.php" ); //redirect after 5 seconds
```

or you prompt a dialog for the user to click to go to next page. remove the header() tho

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   var retVal = confirm("Login FAILED! Do you want to continue ?");
   if( retVal == true ){
      window.location.href = "login.php";
      return true;
   }else{
      alert("User does not want to continue!");
      return false;
   }
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: I've already tried putting it before the header with still no luck.

Comment: @Llama  if you put the header() after the javascript, make sure there is a timer in the header()

Comment: If you put the timer in there it skips the whole login check process and goes straight to the home page after 5 seconds =/

Comment: what file is this code in? you want to redirect to the same file or a different file?

Comment: This is a submit.php file which takes the info from the login.php that the user gives and compares it to a database file. If the login fails I want to give the user another chance of loggin in but displaying the alert message.

Comment: I ended up using the refresh method and just creating a new php file that would make sure it couldn't go to the home page, probably not the best method/idea but hey it works! Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code `header("Location: login.php");` is there before your js code so it never execute js code it redirects to login page remove it and try.

Comment: When I removed the header the alert worked, but how would I still have the redirect to the login page with the alert message appearing?

Comment: @Llama Try adding a query string to the end of your "login.php" redirect so that it looks like "login.php?status=error". Then you can add a conditional that checks $_GET["status"] and output the alert there.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'alert("Password Invalid!");';
echo 'location.href="login.php"';
echo '</script>';
```

instead of

```
header("Location: login.php");
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("Password Invalid!");';
echo '</script>';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that comes after the header doesn't run, maybe try setting a session variable and check for that variable in login.php. You can then call the alert from there, or just show a simple message on the page.

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing semicolon right behind the alert:

```
if($conn) {
    $result=sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Operator
    WHERE Username='{$_POST['login']}'");
    $pass=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
    if($pass["Password"] === $_POST['password']) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin']=true;
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header("Location: login.php");
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Password Invalid!");';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

didnt you check the javscript console ?

EDIT: Sorry, my fault, the semicolon isnt necessary of course.

I testet your php code on my server and it works fine anyway !